# Unix/Linux simple log parser (since, until)

Tags: linux, unix, log-files

Has anyone ever used/created a simple unix/linux log parser that can parse logs like the following:

```
timestamp log_message \n
```

Order the messages, parse the timestamp, and return:

- All messages
- Messages after a certain date (--since)
- Messages before a certain date (--until)
- Combination of --since, --until

I could write something like this, but wasn't sure if there was something canned.  It would fit well in some automated reporting I'm planning on doing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you write such a program, what language would it be in?

Comment: Hi Stefan -- If I write it, it will be Perl, but I was hoping something existed for linux in C (speed) that I could do apt-get install logparse, or similar.  I'm certainly going to look at Dennis' script before I write my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this Python program I wrote](https://serverfault.com/questions/101744/fast-extraction-of-a-time-range-from-syslog-logfile/102531#102531) to see if it comes close to what you're looking for or can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: I will go look at this.  From appearances, it looks like exactly what I need.  I'll probably have to tweak a bit, but that isn't a problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you find one I don't know if I would trust it.  For example, since the timestamp isn't known ahead of time, the only what it could distinguish DD-MM-YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY would be to read ahead until either xx or zz with xx-zz-YYYY is greater than 12.  I am sure there are other issues.

Writing your own would be much easy and more reliable I think as you can use your language's standard string to datetime library and specify the date format specifiers explicitly.

For example with Python:

```
    import re
    from datetime import datetime
    line_regex = re.compile(
        r'''
        \[
        (?P<day> \d{1,2} )
        /
        (?P<month> \w{3} )
        / 
        (?P<year> \d{4} )
        :
        (?P<hour> \d{2} )
        : 
        (?P<minute> \d{2} )
        : 
        (?P<second> \d{2} )
        \s
        (?P<timezone> -?\d{4} )
        \]
        ''', re.VERBOSE)


   new_entry['time'] = datetime.strptime(
        parsed_line['day'] +
        parsed_line['month'] +
        parsed_line['year'] +
        parsed_line['hour'] +
        parsed_line['minute'] +
        parsed_line['second']
        , "%d%b%Y%H%M%S"
   )
```

If you do want a module / library that will try to figure out the format they do exist, one option for Perl is [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/lib/Date/Parse.pm).

Comment: I know the format up front, thanks for the tips.  Also, I have used Date::Parse, it's a bit slow, but it is almost magic. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've ever found for this which was even halfway decent was [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/opensource-logging-system/#) logging to a database (at which point it's reduced to simple SQL queries) -- Assuming you're logging everything centrally this doesn't add too much additional pain.

(Insert obvious benefits & obvious caveats here)

Comment: Good suggestion, not an option in this environment.