# Search log files newer than a time

Tags: linux, shell, log-files, awk

I have a log file which has entries like below. I want to find only the log entries newer than a given time. What would be a suitable shell script for it?

```
[2013-06-23 21:31:19,972]  INFO 
[2013-06-23 21:31:20,148]  INFO 
[2013-06-23 21:31:20,148]  INFO 
[2013-06-23 21:31:20,195]  INFO
```

Comment: May be this will help you
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80088/how-to-find-files-by-the-time-in-their-filename/80089#80089

Comment: You might be able to use my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/102531/1293) as the basis for what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v giventime="2013-06-23 21:31:20,150" '$1" "$2 < "["giventime"]"' logfile
```

If you want to specify the "given time" in a different format, we can accomodate you, but let us know.