# Sed - extract only parts of file with certain timestamps

Tags: linux, log-files, sed

I work with log files on a daily basis. I have been using sed to accomplish my goal of extracting certain lines of data between to time stamps. For example, I use:

```
sed '/20150720 15:06:00/,/20150720 16:25:00/! d' logfile.log > /tmp/logpart.log
```

However, This only works when the timestamps actually match a line in the file. How can I force sed to work on the data that I want without having to go into a file to get the actual time stamps? For instance, in the example above, I just want everything between 15:00 and 16:30, regardless of if there is a matching time stamp in the file.

Comment: Not quite the sed you're looking for, but [an alternative](http://serverfault.com/a/102531/37681)

Comment: Please add a snippet of the logfile.log and sed fragments you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your log files have the good taste of having timestamps that are
lexicographically sorted, you can simple compare strings using awk, eg:

```
awk 'substr($0,1,17)>="20150720 15:06:00" && substr($0,1,17)<="20150720 16:25:00"' <logfile.log
```

I've assumed here that your timestamp starts at column 1 (numbering from 1).
If not, change the `,1,` appropriately.

Comment: Actually, I was able to just use wildcards on the time portions to accomplish what I was after, tested it and it worked. Something like this would work - sed '/20150630 02:20:*/,/20150630 13:40:*/! d' logfile.log > /tmp/logpart.log. This extracted all lines between 2:20 and 13:40.

Comment: @user53029 Good idea. You dont actually need the `*` (which should be `.*`). Just shorten each  pattern until you match a line.

Comment: suggestion: `$1 " " $2 >= "20150720 15:06:00"` (or any other field reference if not first word) instead of substr